# How to implement code for multiple buttons using c++ in Silverlight for Windows Embedded

Tags: c++, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

I have referred the following link:

[Silverlight for Windows Embedded](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122073003/http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx)

By referring this link i created a demo application which consist of two buttons created using Microsoft expression blend 2 tools. And then written a code referring the above site. Now my button names are "Browser Button" and "Media Button". On click of  any one of the button i should able to launch the respective application. I was able to do for "Browser Button" but not for "Media Button" and if i do for "Media Button" then i am not able to do for "Browser Button".. I mean to say that how should i create event handler for both the buttons.

This is the code in c++ which i should modify

```
class BtnEventHandler
{
public:
    HRESULT OnClick(IXRDependencyObject* source,XRMouseButtonEventArgs* args)
    {
        RETAILMSG(1,(L"Browser event"));
        Execute(L"\\Windows\\iesample.exe",L"");
        return S_OK;
    }
};



// entry point for the application.
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
 LPWSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{
    PrintMessage();
    int      exitCode = -1;
    HRESULT  hr = S_OK;

if (!XamlRuntimeInitialize())
    return -1;

HRESULT retcode;
IXRApplicationPtr app;

if (FAILED(retcode=GetXRApplicationInstance(&app)))
    return -1;

if (FAILED(retcode=app->AddResourceModule(hInstance)))
    return -1;

XRWindowCreateParams wp;

ZeroMemory(&wp, sizeof(XRWindowCreateParams));

wp.Style       = WS_OVERLAPPED;
wp.pTitle      = L"Bounce Test";
wp.Left        = 0;
wp.Top         = 0;

XRXamlSource xamlsrc;

xamlsrc.SetResource(hInstance,TEXT("XAML"),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_XAML1));


IXRVisualHostPtr vhost;
if (FAILED(retcode=app->CreateHostFromXaml(&xamlsrc, &wp, &vhost)))
    return -1;  

IXRFrameworkElementPtr root;    
if (FAILED(retcode=vhost->GetRootElement(&root)))
    return -1;  

IXRButtonBasePtr btn;   
if (FAILED(retcode=root->FindName(TEXT("BrowserButton"), &btn)))
    return -1;      

IXRDelegate<XRMouseButtonEventArgs>* clickdelegate;
BtnEventHandler handler;    

if(FAILED(retcode=CreateDelegate
    (&handler,&BtnEventHandler::OnClick,&clickdelegate)))
    return -1;
if (FAILED(retcode=btn->AddClickEventHandler(clickdelegate)))
    return -1;

UINT exitcode;
if (FAILED(retcode=vhost->StartDialog(&exitcode)))
    return -1;

return exitCode;
}
```

I have to add event handler for both the button so that on emulator whenever i click on any one of the button i should be able to launch the respective applications.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code for the 2nd button?

Answer (score 2):

You can create two seperate functions to be the handlers for each button.
If you want the same handler to identify which button was pressed and act accordingly you can read the [following MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503926.aspx) that demonstrates that.

---

I have not tried this, but you can also use [IXRDependencyObject::GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504198.aspx) of the source object to know which button was pressed.

Your handler would look like:

```
HRESULT OnClick(IXRDependencyObject* source,XRMouseButtonEventArgs* args)
{
    BSTR pName[50];

    source->GetName(pName);
    if (_tcscmp(L"BrowserEvent", LPCWSTR(pName)) == 0)
    {
            RETAILMSG(1,(L"Browser event"));
            Execute(L"\\Windows\\iesample.exe",L"");

    }
    else if (_tcscmp(L"BrowserEvent", LPCWSTR(pName)) == 0)
    {
            /* Handle another button or element */
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: @Shaihi: I get error using "_tcscmp" stating that "cannot convert second parameter from BSTR * to const wchar_t *". And when i typecast the second parameter i.e. (_tcscmp(L"BrowserEvent", (const wchar_t *)pName) == 0) then after starting the application at the emulator and clicking on button raises the exception.